# 'tuple' has no attribute colliderect pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Im trying to detect collision between the cross-hair and the target that I've created.

When the collision is detected, the target would disappear from the all sprite groups that its in.

If someone can explain to me why this is happening and maybe suggest a solution Id appreciate it. Thank you!

```
class Cross(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = crosshairImage
        self.rect = crosshairImage
        self.shooting = 0

    def update(self):
        position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.rect = position

    def shoot(self,attack):
        if not self.shooting:
            self.shooting = 1
            return self.rect.colliderect(attack.rect)

    def undo(self):
        self.shooting = 0

class Target0(pygame.sprite.Sprite):    
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = targetImage
        self.rect = targetImage
        self.hp = 1

    def update(self):
        position0 = screen.blit(targetImage, (181.75,204))
        self.rect = position0

while running:
    milliseconds = clock.tick(FPS)
    playtime += milliseconds/1000.0

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            running = False     
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if cross.shoot(target0):
                target0.kill()
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            cross.undo()

    allsprites.update()

    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    allsprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

    text = "FPS: {0:.2f}   Playtime: {1:.2f}".format(clock.get_fps(), playtime)
    pygame.display.set_caption(text) 

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Code is not clear, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pygasm has already mentioned that you have to set the `self.rect` attributes to actual [rect](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) instances instead of the surfaces: `self.rect = self.image.get_rect()` (also change the coordinates of the rect if needed).

The `AttributeError` has its origin in the `update` method of the `Cross` where you set the `self.rect` to the `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` position which is a tuple, and tuples don't have a `colliderect` method which you call in the `shoot` method of the `Cross`.

Instead, you have to update the `center` coords (or one of the other rect attributes) of the rect:

```
def update(self):
    self.rect.center = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put the `get_rect()` value on the rect. Change the `self.rect` values to these and it should work

`self.rect = self.image.get_rect()`